# Can not display data inside input value

Tags: javascript, html, pug

Am trying to display the value of my variable in a textBox using Jade but it is not working>
I tried :
`value="#{startDate}"`
`value="#{{startDate}}"`
`value="{startDate}"`
`value={{startDate}}`

knowing that it is working with placeHolder

Comment: did you try `value=startDate`?

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing your `startDate` variable correctly by doing this in your jade view:

`#{startDate}`

... so that leaves the route: are you inserting the variable into the view correctly in the first place? i.e. something like this (if using Express):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('yourview', { startDate: someDateVariable });
});
```

Comment: If I understood well it has nothing to do with routing

Comment: No, I'm asking / suggesting that you check how you're inserting the value into your view in the first place, because you're referencing the variable in jade correctly. My example shows how an express / jade app handles it (the Express router inserts the `startDate` variable for the jade view to pick up).